# Spring Security replace signing/verifier key

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm writing an Authorization Service that extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter.
Currently, the signing key is being set when the service starts on method accessTokenConverter().
Is there a way to set the key dynamically?
So I could replace the signing key at some point without restarting the service?

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
            final JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
            converter.setSigningKey("secret");
            return converter;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution, I just added that and it made the key modifying available not only when the service starts.

```
 @Autowired
 public JwtAccessTokenConverter tokenConverter;

 public void setPublicKey(String key) {
      tokenConverter.setSigningKey(key);
 }
```